# C++ vector implementation - removing elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, vector

I'm implementing a vector type. I'm not troubled by the algorithms or the data structure at all but I am unsure about a remove method. for instance:

```
bool Remove(Node* node)
{
 /* rearrange all the links and extract the node */

 delete node;
}
```

where node is a pointer to the current node that we are at. But if I delete node then how do I prevent this from happening:

```
Node* currentNode = MoveToRandNode();
Remove(currentNode);
cout << currentNode->value;
```

If currentNode were a pointer to a pointer it would be easier but...it's not.

Comment: So C or C++? The answers will differ greatly depending on the language chosen.

Comment: You cannot prevent this - even documentation will not prevent mistakes (or idiotic users, you just have to let them suffer for a bit)... :)

Comment: Your code looks like C++, not C. Removing something from a vector won't normally involve any links -- it's essentially a wrapper around an array-like structure, not a linked structure. Normally you delete by simply destroying the target object, and moving the ones after it to fill the hole.

Comment: Why are you reimplementing the wheel? Or is this homework? If it is homework please tag it as such.

Comment: Is this "vector" type that you're designing a linked list?  In c++, "vector" is usually assumed to mean something more like an array (eg constant time indexing).

Comment: I'm following a book and trying to be a bit more in-depth and yes it is C++ but I'm not really using OOP - just plain functional programming (so the only difference is delete node -> free(node) ).

Comment: @s5s: The first question is what is your actual data structure. The interface of the `Remove` function does not make much sense with the common understanding of what a vector is (contiguous block of memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step back first.  You need to define who "owns" the memory pointed to by the vector.  Is it the vector itself, or the code that uses the vector?  Once you define this, the answer will be easy - either Remove() method should always delete it or never.

Note that you've just scratched the surface of the possible bugs and you answer to "who owns it" will help with other possible issues like:

- If you copy a vector, do you need to copy the items within it, or just the pointers (e.g. do a shallow or deep copy
- When you destroy a vector, should you destroy the items within it?
- When you insert an item, should you make a copy of the item, or does the vector take ownership of it?

Answer (score 2):

You could add another level of abstraction to your iterator (which now is a raw pointer)
If you do not handle raw pointers, but create some sort of iterator class instead of a pointer, it is possible to invalidate the iterator, and thus failing controlled if anyone tries to access the iterator after it has been removed.

```
 class Iterator {
     Node operator*() {
       if (node) return *node; 
       else throw Something();}
   private:
     Node* node;
 }
```

Of course this wrapping of a pointer will come at a cost of some overhead (checking the pointer on each deref). So you will have to decide how safe you want to play. Either document as suggested by others or wrap for safety.

Answer (score 0):

well, you cannot do that, but some modifications to your code can improve safety.
Add ref

```
bool Remove(Node*& node)
{
 /* rearrange all the links and extract the node */

 delete node;
 node = nullptr;
}
```

check for nullptr

```
if(currentNode)
    cout << currentNode->value;
```

probably you need to try std::shared_ptr

Comment: Doing this can limit the usefulness of the `Remove` function, since you can't call it with a temporary value - e.g. `Remove(getLastNode());`

Comment: It returns a pointer (for example `Node *getLastNode()`). But the pointer it returns is a temporary value and can't be bound to a non-const reference. So `Remove(getLastNode())` wouldn't compile, and you'd need to write it as `Node *node=getLastNode(); Remove(node);`.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to "iterator invalidation".  E.g., if you have a `std::list l` and a `std::list::iterator it` pointing into that list, and you call `l.erase(it)`, then the iterator `it` is invalidated -- i.e., if you use it in any way then you get undefined behavior.

So following that example, you should include in your documentation of the Remove method something along the lines: "the pointer `node` is invalidated, and may not be used or dereferenced after this method returns."

(Of course, you could also just use std::list, and not bother to re-invent the wheel.)

For more info on iterator invalidation, see: http://www.angelikalanger.com/Conferences/Slides/CppInvalidIterators-DevConnections-2002.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In addition what innochenti wrote.
I think you have to decide what is expected/desired behavior of `cout << currentNode->value;`:

- Error - (as innochenti wrote `node = nullptr`)
- Default Value - create node devault_value (which has some default value for its `value`), and after `delete node;` do `node=default_value`

Comment: it will lead to some strange behavior for user.